# parsing Facebook Data fetched with UrlFetchApp.fetch

Tags: arrays, json, facebook-graph-api, google-apps-script

I'm building a little script to import Facebook data directly fetched from the Facebook Api in a Google Sheet. I've been able to successfully authenticate and pass the response of the API call in my Google App script log. However I don't really know how should I proceed to actually pass this data in my sheet.

The following script allow me to log the data from the fb api :

```
function myFunction() {
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/page_id/insights/page_impressions?access_token=mytoken");
 var json = response.getContentText(); // 
  var rawdata = JSON.parse(json);
  var rawdata = Utilities.jsonParse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(rawdata);
```

then I think what I should do is pushing the data I need in a new array with the push method :

```
var data = [];
data.push(rawdata.???) // don't really the name I need to access the data I want
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow(data)
}
```

**My question :**

Since I don't really know how to read the data fetched from the facebook api, I don't really know how to push them in my `data` array. Here is the result of my log :

```
[16-11-21 10:01:33:622 PST] {data=[{period=day,
values=[{end_time=2016-11-17T08:00:00+0000, value=26023596},
{end_time=2016-11-18T08:00:00+0000,value=24447386},
{end_time=2016-11-19T08:00:00+0000, value=31057386}],
name=page_impressions, description=Daily: The number of impressions seen of any content associated with your Page. (Total Count),
id=page_id/insights/page_impressions/day,
title=Daily Total Impressions},
{period=week,
values=[{end_time=2016-11-17T08:00:00+0000, value=233007217},{end_time=2016-11-18T08:00:00+0000, value=200263630},
{end_time=2016-11-19T08:00:00+0000, value=194289364}],
name=page_impressions,
description=Weekly: The number of impressions seen of any content associated with your Page. (Total Count),
id=page_id/insights/page_impressions/week, title=Weekly Total Impressions},
{period=days_28, values=[{end_time=2016-11-17T08:00:00+0000, value=867302439},
{end_time=2016-11-18T08:00:00+0000, value=868201060}, {end_time=2016-11-19T08:00:00+0000, value=874965509}],
name=page_impressions, description=28 Days: The number of impressions seen of any content associated with your Page. (Total Count),
id=page_id/insights/page_impressions/days_28, title=28 Days Total Impressions}],
paging={next=https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/page_id/insights/page_impressions?access_token=my_token,
previous=https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/page_id/insights/page_impressions?access_token=my_token}}
```

If an example is needed to illustrate an answer let's say I want the Daily Total Impressions for the three days facebook gave me.

I hope my issue is clear enough. Not sure which tag should I use for this question. Correct me if I'm wrong.

thanks !

Comment: You need to decide what data to push into an array to then drop into a sheet. I would first drop your raw log file into a [JSON prettifier](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) so it's easy to see the formatting. Then, [take a look at how to manipulate JSON](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external) using apps script.

Comment: You should pass your comment as an answer. It help to move on and build another question, more structured. thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide what data to push into an array to then drop into a sheet. I would first drop your raw log file into a [JSON prettifier](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) so it's easy to see the formatting. Then, [take a look at how to manipulate JSON](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external) using apps script.